How to display data from Google Sheet in a Section Header within a Google Form?
I have a Google spreadsheet that lists customers and identifies store locations for each:



Customer
Location




Customer A
New York


Customer A
San Jose


Customer B
New York



I have a Google Form that will ask the user what their customer name is (Customer A).
Based on this, I want to show a list of all the locations currently entered into the Google Spreadsheet within the Google Form as regular text.
For example, if Customer A started to use the form, it would show 'New York, San Jose' in a text field.
I've been trying to create an Apps Script to query the spreadsheet, filter the results based on the customer name, and then log the results as the description (or HelpText) for a SectionHeaderItem.
However, I'm not having a lot of luck. Most of the related questions I can find deal with how to create new questions based off of spreadsheet data, not just how to display the information.
Any thoughts would be most welcome!

From what I understand, what you'd like to do is similar to Send a form with pre-filled answers, but you'd like to show a list of all the locations currently entered into the Google Spreadsheet based on the name a user will enter. Can you elaborate on what should happen after Customer A started to use the form, it would show 'New York, San Jose' in a text field.? It's best if you show the community what the form looks like and what you're expecting to get before and after running the script.

Say the first question of the form is 'What is the customer's name?'. The answer to that would then be used to filter the contents of the spreadsheet. The next section of the form would then show a list of all the locations, followed by another question.
For example:
What is the customer's name? Customer A
Here are all the current known locations:
New York
San Jose
Would you like to add another location?

Google Forms does not include the feature of a dynamic, real-time link to Google Sheets

I realize that, but I was hoping to be able to use the app Script function to populate the description field of a Section Header...

Do you have a simple example script that doesn't meet your needs? Can you include it into the question and explain why it's not behaving as expected.

I was hoping to be able to use the app Script function to populate the description field of a Section Header Right, I'm sorry it can't be done. Apps scripts don't run while the form is open.  All/any apps scripts (Forms and Sheets) are going to run after a form has been submitted. So, there's no "native" method to update the content of a Form in real-time.

Related question: Write Google Form Dynamic Content Before Submitting. This question refers to a "a 3rd party plugin that I can pay for" that appears to update Form fields prior to submitting. The answer to this question discusses the functionality of Google Forms API and also includes a link to a feature quest.

This question is similar to: How to add a simple calculated field to a google form?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Tedinoz is correct. When creating a Google Form using Google Apps Script, the form structure is created within the script, so what you described isn't currently possible. This goes the same when using the trigger onFormSubmit(). Reviewing their linked questions should also give you more insight about this.
